# How do I include an Ajax call as an external file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, external

I have a simple Ajax call which works perfectly when I wrap it in the document ready function in a script before the closing body tag in my HTML file. However, when I try to move the call into an external .js file, excluding script tags and the document ready function, the call does not work. I have tried adding the external file in both the head and body of the HTML file like this without any success:

```
<script src="includes_js/login3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I did not include much code here because I am not sure what might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`However, when I try to move the call into an external .js file, excluding script tags and the document ready function`

Try adding the document ready function to your external java script file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 alert('worked');
 // ajax call here
});
```

If the alert gets run that means your external java script file is being loaded.  Otherwise something may be wrong with the path in your `<script>` tag.

Comment: I did have a path issue. I fixed that and added the document ready function to the external file (for some reason I thought I did not need in an external file) and working.

Comment: Is there a recommendation as to where to load the external script file, in the head tag or just before the body close tag?

Comment: From what I have read it is better to load the script file from just before the closing body tag.  There are cases where it can take a while to load the script and if you have the script in the header tag it can slow down the loading of your page.  Whereas if you have the script at the end of the body then the user can see the whole webpage load first before the script loads. So having the script in the bottom of the body tag can offer a better user experience when opening your page.

Answer (score 0):

You can call js methods from external files like below way.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: encodeURI("../CtrlName/MethodName"), // adjust your path
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({ "param": _param }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```